# Get the value of the script tag that was dynamically added

Tags: javascript, dynamic, browser

Say we have this code in a JS file:

```
let element = document.createElement('script');

element.innerText = 'function Test() { alert("Hello!"); }';
document.head.appendChild(element);
```

Can the client output the content of that script tag (ie: function Test() { ... } ) using their browser's development tool or any other tools after the element was created and added to the DOM?

Comment: What do you mean by *"output the content of that script tag"*? Can certainly call that function in console and will trigger the alert within the window if that's what you mean

Comment: Can the user output or get the JavaScript code we dynamically added or that information is very hard to get a hold off as it is stored in memory?  The user does not know we created a function called Test().

Comment: Sure. Can see it in browser dev tools and copy from there and can also query that script element from console and get the textContent out of it just as easily as you put it in there